# Using PHP and Nodejs Socket.io

Tags: php, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm running NodeJS on port 3001

My index.php :

```
  ...
  ...
 <div class="chat">
      <ul id="chat-ul">
        <?php foreach ($msgs as $key): ?>
          <li id="<?= $key['id'] ?>"><b><?=$key['username']?>: </b> <?=$key['message']?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="chat-form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="sendMsg()" type="button" name="button">SEND</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" name="message" id="message" class="form-control" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


<script src="http://mywebsite:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect("http://mywebsite.com:3001");
function sendMsg() {
  socket.emit('send_message', {user:<?= $_SESSION['username']?>, id:0, message:$('#message').val()});
}
socket.on('received_message', (e)=>{
  $('#chat-ul').append(e);
});
</script>
```

In the backend - server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var server = app.listen(3001);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket)=>{
  console.log('connected'); // connected

  socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
    console.log('disconnected');
  });
  
  socket.on('send_message', (data)=>{
    let new_data = '<li id='+data.id+'><b>'+data.username+':</b>'+data.message+'</li>'; //connected
    io.sockets.emit('received_message', new_data); })
 
  });
```

When I try to run sendMsg() function, in the consol says:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME  socket.io.js:1
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined at index.php:97

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can simply use PHP and JS via [Ratchet](http://socketo.me).

Comment: isnt it possible with socket.io in php?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it is very close to being correct.

This error has to do with the fact that your file `http://mywebsite:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js` is not being loaded correctly, thus the `io` variable is never assigned the socket io library.

It seems to me that you changed the url not to reveal your domain, but I am afraid that is exactly where the problem resides.

Make sure that if you put that url in your browser, it takes you to the file. It looks like the url has some invalid format.

Comment: You were right, i was entering url wrong. Thank you.

When i enter that http://mtwebsite.com:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js
my users can easily see that the server is working on port 3001, is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: @AldenWillms You can save and store the `socket.io.js` somewhere on your php server. Still, people will always be able to see the webpage connects to port 3001. Also, when you do this you need to make sure your keep the right `socket.io.js` version on your php server